# How to configure threshold and frustration values for html dashboard creation in jmeter

Tags: html, groovy, jmeter

I have done a performance run on a rest server and generated jtl file 
After that I want to generate html dashboard out of jtl file, but it comes with default threshold and frustration values which I want to configure.

How to configure the THRESHOLD and FRUSTRATION values in html dash board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See JMeter's [Generating Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

> **General settings**
>   All properties must be prefixed with
>   `jmeter.reportgenerator`.
>
> `apdex_satisfied_threshold` Sets the satisfaction threshold for the APDEX calculation (in ms).
>   Default: 500  No
>
> `apdex_tolerated_threshold` Sets the tolerance threshold for the APDEX calculation (in ms).
>   Default: 1500

You need to update `reportgenerator.properties` found in JMeter bin folder with relevant values as:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500
```

Comment: I have changed the values but it is not reflecting in the report creation, i am using command .\jmeter -g ".jtl" -o ".html"             i execute the command in cmd in admin mode, but still not working

Comment: Do i have to set these values before i start the run?

Comment: @venkatsai yes, to load the properties

Answer (score 0):

Changing in jmeter.reportgenerator did not apply changes in HTML report for me but changing in **jmeter.properties(In "bin" folder) did work**, not sure why its in 2 places when it does not work in jmeter.reportgenerator